# What should I do to upload React Native CLI Released APK on Google Playstore?

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error on "https://play.google.com/apps/publish/" while uploading the 'app-release.apk'.
"You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Learn more about signing."

What should I do to overcome this error? Please help if anyone has any idea regarding this.

I am uploading the signed APK that is located in app-release folder. I did not find any problem this. And also app is running successfully in the phone

Comment: Check this Article: https://www.instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as documentation says [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android):

- generate an upload key
- set up your gradle variables correctly
- add signing config for **release mode**
- generate the signed apk or bundle

Answer (score 1):

Please check this react-native link [react-native-publishing-toplaystore](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) .

You have to create a key file  and place it in folder , please see the below steps and in the official link ive posted , youll get every details what to be done :

> 1.Generating an upload key
>
> 2.Setting up Gradle variables
>
> 3.Adding signing config to your app's Gradle config
>
> 4.Generating the release APK

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can only upload release build on google play store.So create release build to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Now, what I had change is change the the mode in build types in release section i.e.
signingConfig signingConfigs.release. Earlier it was signingConfig signingConfigs.debug.
That's why I faced that problem. This is build.gradle in app section.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
             minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
```